# Pycharm error .whl

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to install the blocktrail package into pycharm, but everytime it gives me an error:

```
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/h/httpsig/httpsig-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=71bf1b61f1f6c5225f196872ce1d7d12 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/httpsig/); unknown archive format: .whl
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement httpsig>=1.1.0 (from blocktrail-sdk)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in PyCharm I have the packages: pip, pip-tools, pip-upgrade, setuptools installed but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.whl` should be a `wheel` file, which is simply a zip file with a well-defined content. If your installer doesn't support it, try updating it and installing the `wheel` package.